# How to generate a backtrace to debug a segmentation fault without debug symbols

Tags: c++, debugging, c++11, segmentation-fault, shared-libraries

so I have a few projects that are shipped to production. some conditions arise that result in segmentation faults.
I feel a backtrace is the best and fastest way to debug the issue(if any other ways exist I am all ears).

But without debug symbols I am completely lost.

Comment: You have to find the address of the instruction that causes the crash, and then find the corresponding instruction in a debug-build of the executable.